# flask run loop and update its output in html

Tags: python, flask, multiprocessing

I am building flask app in order to make below possible:

1. visit "localhost/run"(ajax), it run a loop in flask, the loop print output using `print('')`.
2. html text-area keep getting output from item 1 (maybe ajax "localhost/update" here?)
3. visit "localhost/stop"(ajax), to stop the item 1's loop

I had search many about multi-thread, process, Celery, but it seem I can't find a solution to achieve above.

update on what i have so far:

```
pp=None
@simple_page.route('/stop')
def stopApp():
    pp.join()

@simple_page.route('/run')
def runApp():
    pp = Process(target=theAppLoop, args=('',))
    pp.daemon = True
    pp.start()

@simple_page.route('/update')
def updateMonitor():
    #return pp's print('')?

def theAppLoop(s):
    while True:
        run_cycle()

def run_cycle():
    #call others func and those func will do print('')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after few more search, for the problem of "flask run loop and update its output in html
", I solved by socket